# live data failed to be retrieved in my fragment from Firebase database using MVVM

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, mvvm

I am fairly new to programming and I am using java. my problem is I am trying to fetch live data from firebase database using MVVM Architecture, following an online tutorial but nothing is being displayed/fetched in my fragment. No error shown whatsoever in the entire project, I don't know where I went wrong.

here is my code:

Repository code:

```
package com.example.echat.Repository;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;


import com.example.echat.Utils.Util;
import com.example.echat.UserModel;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

 public class ProfileRepository {

    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private Util util = new Util();
    private MutableLiveData<UserModel> liveData;
    private static ProfileRepository profileRepository;

    public static ProfileRepository getInstance(){
        return profileRepository = new ProfileRepository();
    }


    public LiveData<UserModel>getUser(){
        if (liveData==null) {
            liveData=new MutableLiveData<>();
            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
            databaseReference.child(util.getUID()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                        UserModel userModel = snapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
                        liveData.setValue(userModel);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
        }
        return liveData;
    }
}
```

Util code:

```
package com.example.echat.Utils;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class Util {
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    public String getUID(){
        firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        return firebaseAuth.getUid();
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
package com.example.echat.ViewModel;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

import com.example.echat.Repository.ProfileRepository;
import com.example.echat.UserModel;

public class ProfileViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<UserModel> userModelMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    ProfileRepository profileRepository = ProfileRepository.getInstance();

    public LiveData<UserModel> getUser(){
        return profileRepository.getUser();

    }
}
```

Profile Fragment:

```
package com.example.echat.Fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.example.echat.UserModel;
import com.example.echat.ViewModel.ProfileViewModel;
import com.example.echat.databinding.FragmentProfileBinding;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link ProfileFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
    private FragmentProfileBinding binding;
    private ProfileViewModel profileViewModel;


    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public ProfileFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment ProfileFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static ProfileFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ProfileFragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding=FragmentProfileBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);
        View view = binding.getRoot();

        profileViewModel= ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(getActivity().getApplication()).create(ProfileViewModel.class);

        Observer<UserModel> observer = userModel -> {
            binding.setUserModel(userModel);

            String name = userModel.getName();
            if (name.contains(" ")) {
                String[] split = name.split(" ");
                binding.txtProfileFName.setText(split[0]);
                binding.txtProfileLName.setText(split[1]);
            } else {
                binding.txtProfileFName.setText(name);
                binding.txtProfileLName.setText("");
            }

        };
        profileViewModel.getUser().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),observer);
        return view;
    }
}
```

UserModel:

```
package com.example.echat;

import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class UserModel {

    String name, status, image, number, uID, online, typing, token;

    public UserModel() {
    }

    public UserModel(String name, String status, String image, String number, String uID, String online, String typing, String token) {
        this.name = name;
        this.status = status;
        this.image = image;
        this.number = number;
        this.uID = uID;
        this.online = online;
        this.typing = typing;
        this.token = token;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public String getTyping() {
        return typing;
    }

    public void setTyping(String typing) {
        this.typing = typing;
    }

    public String getOnline() {
        return online;
    }

    public void setOnline(String online) {
        this.online = online;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getuID() {
        return uID;
    }

    public void setuID(String uID) {
        this.uID = uID;
    }

    @BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
    public static void loadImage(@NonNull CircleImageView view, @NonNull String image) {
        Glide.with(view.getContext()).load(image).into(view);
    }


}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted more than **500** (five hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @AlexMamo noted Bro, let me work on that